# Using Custom Exception in multiple classes

Tags: java

Hello im having trouble with handling my custom exception.
My Exception is supposed to be thrown when the user does not enter a first and last name Here is code from each class:

```
public class EmployeeException extends Exception{
    public EmployeeException(String message){
        super("invalid");
    }
}   

public abstract class Employee{
    private String employeeName;
    private String departmentName;

    public Employee(String employeeName, String departmentName)throws EmployeeException{
        String [] tokens= employeeName.split(" ");

        if(tokens.length!=2)
            throw new EmployeeException("please use space to separate first and last name");

        this.employeeName=employeeName;
        this.departmentName=departmentName;
    }
```

This is the driver where i'm getting unreported exception error . the instrustion stated the driver didnt need to be informed of exception

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompanyDriver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String compStreet;
        String compCity;
        String compState;
        String compZip;

        System.out.print("What is the name of the company?");
        name=kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What is the address of the company?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Street:"); 
        compStreet=kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("City:");
        compCity=kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("State:");
        compState=kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Zip:");
        compZip=kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        Address addr =new Address(compStreet, compCity, compState, compZip);

        Company comp=new Company(name, addr);
        System.out.println(comp);
        comp.addEmployee();
        comp.addEmployee();
        comp.weeklyPayReport();
```

basically my program is supposed to throw my custom exception whenever the user does not enter 2 tokens for employee name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: When you ask about an error, post the complete and exact error message, and tell which line of code is referenced in the message. Note that the Employee class isn't used anywhere in the posted code, so it's hard to understand why it's relevant.

Comment: 2 Unreported Exception error must be caught or declared to be thrown  the error is from the line where comp.addemployee() is  in the driver

Comment: `EmployeeException` extends `Exception` and must be wrapped in a `try-catch` block or declared using `throws` (like you did in your `Employee` constructor).

Comment: nyname00 can you clarify which class you are referring too

Comment: @tbray1 your `Employee` class declares `throws EmployeeException` in it's constructor, where `EmployeeException` extends `Exception`. I guess, your `Company.addEmployee()` method creates an instance of (a sub-class of) `Employee`. Therefore you would have to catch the exception in `addEmployee` (or in your `main`) or add an other `throws`.